# How do I prevent randomly injected repeat characters in vim

Tags: vim

I sometimes encounter the following behaviour when editing large files in vim (it only appears to occur with > 500 lines).

When creating a sentence in insert mode occasionally a character will be repeated on screen (the `v` in `visual`):

[image: example of error]

Changing to normal mode and moving to the line below removes the errant letter (the `v` is removed):

[image]

The closest issue I could find while searching for a solution was described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/329154/ssh-garbling-characters-in-vim-nano-on-remote-server) - in my case setting the `TERM` variable to `xterm-color` (as opposed to the current setting of `xterm-256color`) was not effective.

Any suggestions for how to debug this would be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine it's more likely to be a plugin than vim itself. Try disabling some/all and see what happens?

Comment: Good call. In my case it was related to the [GitGutter plugin](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter) in combination with setting the `updatetime` interval to be too small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Holloway, it was related to a plugin.  In my case, when following the install instructions for [GitGutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter), I had reduced the `updatetime` to be `250ms`.  I was able to resolve my issue by increasing this (`set updatetime=2500`).  The plugin is a little less responsive, but it's still extremely useful and I no longer get the repeat errors.